# Thermostat wiring help?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

Can anyone tell me what’s going on with my thermostat wiring? Some are pretty straight forward but my questions are: why is my G wire blue? And why does my Y terminal have a white and yellow wire running to it?

---

[image]

Here is the terminal and wires

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site!

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace please?

Comment: I will take a SWAG and guess it is the only multi conductor cable the contractor had at the time. Check the other end. Electrons don't care about the color of insulation but people do.

Comment: Yes probably used two leftover pieces of phone wire, one for heat, one for AC hence two reds, two whites.  Two Y connections you'd have to find the other ends to see what they do.  Two zones controlled by one stat?